# Installing a Java jar from a download

Tags: software-installation, java

I'm trying to install and run a program a called *Remotedroid*, which lets you use your phone as a wireless keyboard and mouse. I'm used to windows automatically starting setup upon download and can't figure out how to initiate the install in Ubuntu.

The program's website says its compatible with Linux and the readme file says to just click the extension `remotedroidserver.jar` to use, but it won't work and none of the files do anything.

I've unzipped all the files and my Java is all up to date as far as i know, I think. I'm just not getting how to run a setup in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Make sure you have either  [openjdk-6-jre[image: Install openjdk-6-jre]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openjdk-6-jre)* *(recommended)* or if that doesn't work,
   [sun-java6-bin[image: Install sun-java6-bin]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/sun-java6-bin) installed.

   <sub>*editor's note - replace 6 with 7, 8 or 9 etc as appropriate to your Ubuntu version</sub>
2. Once that is installed, right-click on **RemoteDroidServer.jar** and select **Properties**. In the **Permissions** tab, check **Allow executing file as a program**.

   [image]
3. In the **Open With** tab, select **OpenJDK Java 6 Runtime**. If that doesn't run your program,
   try **Sun Java 6 Runtime**.

   [image]
4. Now double-clicking on **RemoteDroidServer.jar** should work as expected.

   [image]

Comment: Unless it really doesn't work with OpenJDK, I wouldn't suggest to use Sun Java, as it has integration issues with things like PulseAudio.

Comment: @JanC Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the advice. it opened perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

if you want it to run on CLI, assuming you have java installed, you can run it like this

```
java -jar
/location/of/your/jar/file/file.jar &
```